# Add class "active" in existing jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I want to add class "active" in existing jQuery code I'm not quite good in jQuery I try but I'm not lucky enough.

i want to add class "active" for active state

I have a sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/CNgJM/2/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#arrow').click(function() {
        $('.toggleContent').slideToggle('fast');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Add `active` to what?  And in what context?

Comment: hi i want to add class for active state http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/CNgJM/2/

Comment: What's wrong with @Blender's answer?

Comment: hi @Explosion Pills someone do this to make it work but the problem is when i click it again, it always perform the active state the normal state don't back sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/CNgJM/5/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add it to the arrow that was clicked, use `$(this)`:

```
$('#arrow').click(function(event) {
    $('.toggleContent').slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    event.preventDefault();
});
```